# Covering circular patio area with geotextile

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I have a circular patio area of diameter 3m, currently being built. I also have a roll of geotextile, and its width is 2m - so I can cut only rectangular pieces of geotextile with one measure 2m.

What is the minimal number of such geotextile pieces that can cover the patio area so that each point of the area is covered by at least 5 layers of geotextile?

(That number obviously must be less than or equal 10, but greater than 5)

Comment: If you may fold, one piece is enough ;-) In fact, I am not sure that the number of pieces is the right parameter. Rather the total length.

Comment: @Yves That would be another interesting problem if I want to minimise number of folds or length used. :)

Comment: Are you willing to cut the geotextile down the center into strips 1m wide?

Comment: @John, no, I am not.